# The number of points of inflection on the curve $y=\arccos(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$ is/are

Tags: calculus

The number of points of inflection on the curve $y=\arccos(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$ is/are
$(A)1\hspace{1cm}(B)2\hspace{1cm}(C)3\hspace{1cm}(D)0$

---

How to find the number of points of inflection of a function?Please tell me the method.Thanks.

Comment: May be the second derivative ?

Comment: the second derivative...compare with $x^3$ at $0$ case

Answer (score 5):

First, note that since $\arccos$ is defined on $[-1,1]$, you need $-1 \le \dfrac {2x} {1+x^2} \le 1$, which gives $x \in \Bbb R$, so the functions is defined on $\Bbb R$.

Next, compute the first derivative: $y'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll} \dfrac {-2} {1+x^2}, && x \in (-1,1) \\ \dfrac 2 {1+x^2}, && x \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \end{array} \right.$. Note that $y'$ is not continuous in $-1$ and $1$; since the lateral derivatives in these points are finite, they are *corners* of the graph. Even though the graph changes its convexity when passing through them, they are not considered inflection points.

Finally, compute the second derivative: $y''(x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll} \dfrac {4x} {(1+x^2)^2}, && x \in (-1,1) \\ \dfrac {-4x} {(1+x^2)^2}, && x \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \end{array} \right.$ and find those points where it changes sign: from $-\infty$ to $-1$ it is positive, it suddenly changes sign in $-1$ but we have ruled this out, it changes from negative to positive when passing through $0$, again it changes sign abruptly in $1$ but this one does not count, and from $1$ to $\infty$ it stays negative.

Therefore, $y$ has a single inflection point at $0$ and it also changes convexity at $-1$ and $1$, but these are not considered inflection points.

Comment: I was reading this question and your solution,i do not understand here why $-1,1$ are not considered the inflection points even though the curve changes its concavity when passing through them.@Alex M.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: This is a matter of definition. The definition that I use requires the function not only to change concavity at an inflection point, but also to be derivable at such a point (which the given function is not). If you agree to relax this condition, then you may consider such "pathological" points as well.